# How to use substitute variable in sqlplus? IN condition

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I faced an error when i actually use ampersand for the input, it does not return the record

When I hardcoded the name, it was able to show the record.
The name I entered for example is 'customer something', with a space in between.

Is it something to do with the input not being able to accept the space? So how can solve it to return the record inside IN?

```
WHERE
    name IN ('&name');
```

Comment: Please show us the error ? Thanks!

Comment: Hi ZH do you have sample data please

Comment: Did you define the name variable?

Comment: You wouldn't normally use `in` with a single value; so are you actually looking for a single value, or expecting the words in your value to be looked up separately? What does `show define` report - maybe you have substitution variables disabled, or using a different character? Is it prompting you for the `name` value, or have you previously `define`d it?

Answer (score 1):

Quote the substitution string when prompted, don't quote the substitution text in the query itself.

```
SQL> select &message from dual;
Enter value for message: hello mom
old   1: select &message from dual
new   1: select hello mom from dual
select hello mom from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "HELLO": invalid identifier


SQL> select &message from dual;
Enter value for message: 'Hello, Mom!'
old   1: select &message from dual
new   1: select 'Hello, Mom!' from dual

'HELLO,MOM!
-----------
Hello, Mom!

SQL> create table so_ampersand (message varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into so_ampersand values ('Hello, Mom!');

1 row created.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select * from so_ampersand where message in (&mess);
Enter value for mess: 'Hello, Mom!'
old   1: select * from so_ampersand where message in (&mess)
new   1: select * from so_ampersand where message in ('Hello, Mom!')

MESSAGE
--------------------
Hello, Mom!

SQL>
```

Or, the other way around..

```
SQL> select * from so_ampersand where message in ('&mess2');
Enter value for mess2: Hello, Mom!
old   1: select * from so_ampersand where message in ('&mess2')
new   1: select * from so_ampersand where message in ('Hello, Mom!')

MESSAGE
--------------------
Hello, Mom!
```

Comment: Quoting the variable reference is OK too - `select '&message' from dual;` then supplying `Hello, Mom!` at the prompt without quotes still works?